# Need help for webkit bug fix in responsive email

Tags: outlook, gmail, webkit, html-email

My template looks responsive in Litmus' gmail versions, but is actually isn't, even though I am **not** using attribute selectors and my webkit fix is on the div tag. I'm also getting a major shift on Outlook 2016. I'm sure the error is minor but I can't find it. Thanks.

Here's my body tag:

CSS:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width:600px) {
    .mw35 {
      width: 35% !important;
    }
    .mw65 {
      width: 65% !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
    <!-- STORY 2 CONTENT -->
      <tr>
        <td><!--[if mso | IE]> <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" style="width:600px;"> <tr> <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"> <![endif]-->
          
          <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;">
            <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="left" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border:0px;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 40px; display: inline-block;"><!--[if mso | IE]> <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr> <td style="vertical-align:top;width:35%;"> <![endif]-->
                  
                  <div class="mw35" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0px;vertical-align:middle;" width="100%" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding: 0px 15px 20px 0px;" align="left"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="left" border="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #323232; text-decoration: underline;"><img alt="image 2" height="auto" src="https://dummyimage.com/154x121/ecf8fb/fff" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;"  width="308"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  
                  <!--[if mso | IE]> </td><td style="vertical-align:top;width:65%;"> <![endif]-->
                  
                  <div class="mw65" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:16px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0px;vertical-align:top;" width="100%" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#F15B5D;font-family:'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif; text-align:left;"> <span style="margin: 0; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color:#333333; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; font-weight:normal;"><b>LOREM IPSUM 2</b></span> </div></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color: #727272;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:25.2px;text-align:left;">
                            <p style="margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                          </div></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 30px 0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="left" border="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="border:1px solid rgba(230,236,238,1);border-radius:4px;color:#FFFFFF;cursor:auto;padding:10px 20px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; background: #FFFFFF; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%; text-transform: none; margin: 0px;" target="_blank"><span>CTA</span></a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  
                  <!--[if mso | IE]> </td></tr></table> <![endif]--></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
```

Here are screen shots of how it lays correctly vs the entire body shift. Also, the responsive fix which appears correctly.

correct display
[image: correct display]

shifted
[image: shifted]

responsive display
[image: responsive display]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Gmail, I'm guessing you might be using a mobile Gmail app (iOS or Android) with a non Gmail account (like an Outlook.com email address for example). This specific case, often referred to as GANGA (for Gmail Apps with Non Gmail Accounts), doesn't support `<style>` tags and thus media queries ([as reported on Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media/)). In order to get your email to work in GANGA, you must code it with a fluid/hybrid or mobile first approach so that the layout can work even without media queries.

As for Outlook, I'm not sure what major shift you're referring to. One thing I see though is that your code is not ready for Outlook at 120 dpi rendering, and that could be part of your issue. [As documented here](https://www.courtneyfantinato.com/correcting-outlook-dpi-scaling-issues/), to get a good rendering in Outlook at 120dpi, you need to:

1. Add the `xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"` namespace in your `<html>` tag.
2. Add the `<!--[if mso]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->` declaration in your `<head>`.
3. Use the `width` property in CSS instead of the `width` attribute in HTML.
4. Use the `width` attribute on image elements with the desired width for Outlook. (Here your image is set at `width="308"` while it should only be displayed at 154px in Outlook on desktop. So it should be `width="154"` instead).

Here’s a full email code I adjusted and tests.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Need help for webkit bug fix in responsive email</title>
    <style>
        @media only screen and (min-width:600px) {
            .mw35 {
                width: 35% !important;
            }
            .mw65 {
                width: 65% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;" align="center">
         <!-- STORY 2 CONTENT -->
      <tr>
        <td><!--[if mso | IE]> <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" style="width:600px;"> <tr> <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"> <![endif]-->
          
          <div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;">
            <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="left" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border:0px;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 40px; display: inline-block;"><!--[if mso | IE]> <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;"> <tr> <td style="vertical-align:top;width:35%;"> <![endif]-->
                  
                  <div class="mw35" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0px;vertical-align:middle;" width="100%" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding: 0px 15px 20px 0px;" align="left"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="left" border="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #323232; text-decoration: underline;"><img alt="image 2" height="auto" src="https://dummyimage.com/154x121/ecf8fb/fff" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;"  width="154"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  
                  <!--[if mso | IE]> </td><td style="vertical-align:top;width:65%;"> <![endif]-->
                  
                  <div class="mw65" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:16px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                    <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0px;vertical-align:top;" width="100%" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#F15B5D;font-family:'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif; text-align:left;"> <span style="margin: 0; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color:#333333; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; font-weight:normal;"><b>LOREM IPSUM 2</b></span> </div></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color: #727272;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:25.2px;text-align:left;">
                            <p style="margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                          </div></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 30px 0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="left" border="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="border:1px solid rgba(230,236,238,1);border-radius:4px;color:#FFFFFF;cursor:auto;padding:10px 20px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; background: #FFFFFF; color: #333333; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%; text-transform: none; margin: 0px;" target="_blank"><span>CTA</span></a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  
                  <!--[if mso | IE]> </td></tr></table> <![endif]--></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find a [test run for this code on Email on Acid here](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/7YMrEZtCsJKaut5cdBKpfkjGClCggI0P2fxsYefUM9AvP/list).

Comment: Thank you and sorry I should have included my code heading, I do have your #1 & #2 suggestions included. Maybe my ghost table setting is off? Your remedy helps the stack but my images do not scale on mobile.

Comment: Could you provide actual screenshots of the problem you have with the code I posted and the result you’re expecting?

Comment: I updated with 3 pics: correct display, shifted and responsive with small images. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Could you post the entire code of the email you're testing? As you can see in my tests above, there's is no shift in Outlook from the sample you posted. This means the shift comes from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I can't tell where because the body didn't shift before. I'm not sure if I even need the ghost table now.